# How can I set up a boolean expression that can execute in both C# and SQL, without depending on libraries like EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, expression, boolean-expression

I want to have an app where a user (typically a power user) can enter a boolean expression. I want to be able to execute the boolean expression in both .NET and in SQL.

The expressions themselves aren't that hard, they are things like:

- country is united states
- country is one of: united states, canada, mexico
- (country is united states) AND (age is 20)
- (country is united states) OR ((age is 20) and country is one of: united states, canada)

I need to be able to support basic things like 'in', equals, greater/less than, between, contains, startswith, etc. I want to be able to compile into C# and run it against an object of type `dynamic`, and also be able to compile the expression into SQL. I would be plugging the result into a where clause of a very specific query.

I do not want to use Nhibernate or EntityFramework, I want to be able to execute the SQL directly.

**UPDATE:** 
I already know that I want to execute it using ADO.NET. Sorry if I didn't state it clearly. I just want to know what a good approach would be to store a boolean expression that can be executed both in C# and SQL. I don't care about stored procedures and parameterization (the latter is obvious and trivial once I'm able to generate a query). The users entering the expressions are internal to my company, mostly developers and power users.

So I'm thinking along the lines of using things like Expression Trees, Abstract Syntax Trees, LINQ, etc, to accomplish this. I don't want to use an ORM, but I want to do something very similar to what the ORM's do in their LINQ expressions to convert lambas into the code for the `WHERE` clause.

**UPDATE2:** 
The way we're thinking of doing this so far is having the expressions entered as C# and stored as strings in a database. When we want to execute in a .NET context we'd compile into a lambda or Expression and maybe wrape it in an object that as an interface with a method to represent the boolean expression `interface IDynamicFilter { bool PassesFilter<SomePocoType>(poco); }`. Or we could drop the POCO(s) into an IEnumerable and run a LINQ .Where() with the lambda/expression passed in to pull out the objects that match the filters.

For the SQL, this is the part I'm more fuzzy on. We want to replicate what the ORM's do -- visit an Expresssion tree and render it into an SQL string. We don't need to support the full set of SQL. We only have to support pretty simple operators like grouping with parentheses, AND/OR/NOT, in/not in, GT/LT/EQ/NEQ/between. We also want to support some basic maths operations (`a + b > c`).

Comment: "execute the sql directly"... you mean write a dynamic query?  Look up ADO.NET.  It sounds like you want to use a `SqlCommand`.  Just make sure you parameterize it to protect against SQL injection attacks.

Comment: What are you going to execute it against in c# and sql? I mean, what will represent the (possible) values of country, age, etc? In sql you "would be plugging the result into a where clause of a very specific query". What about c#?

Comment: Also you don't want to use ORM but you want to do what ORMs accomplish. Can you explain why?

Comment: We need to be able to convert into SQL and use it in various places -- console apps that will pull out all data that matches each expression. Other worker processes will find entities that match the expressions and perform operations on them. Other times we'd dump the expressions into .sql template files for non-techies to run from an SSMS-like tool. Any of these queries may have parts to them like pulling in data from linked servers, steps that generate temp tables, CTE's, aggregations, etc.

Comment: @zespri, in C# I would be executing against either POCO's, `dynamic`'s, or a dictionary of strings, whichever works best. We haven't designed that part yet so I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft CRM has something like this where they give you the form fields and a drop down designating what you're trying to find and what your logical operator is, so you might have.

```
Column:
Select Column in Database

Opeartor: 
>
<
>=
<=
LIKE
=
IN
NOT IN

Value:
TextBox for user input
```

So you would take the user input and just create the queries based upon that. If you don't want to use an ORM like Entity, then you could use ADO.NET.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, you can do something like this (and keep in mind I do not recommend this sort of thing for production):

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE as T WHERE 1=1";

if ([some condition]) query += " AND T.CountryCode = 'USA'";
if ([some other condition]) query += " AND T.CountryCode IN ('USA', 'CAN', 'MEX')";
if ([yet another condition]) query += " AND T.CountryCode = 'USA' AND T.Age = 20";

using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (var comm = new SqlCommand(conn, query))
    {
        var results = comm.ExecuteReader();  //returns an IDataReader you can loop through.
    }
}
```

I'll say again, make sure you are parameterizing any variables you are searching on, this sort of query is quite vulnerable to sql injection.  This is the lazy developer's way of doing something, and can be quite dangerous.  If you want to avoid ORM's, this sort of logic should be in a stored procedure that you pass parameters to.

Comment: I can't hardcode `if`'s, that's' not what I'm trying to do. I want to dynamically store boolean expressions into a database. Then I want to be able to execute that definition within a C# context, as well as within a SQL context. The table properties when executed in SQL will always correspond to those of the C# object whose properties are checked in the boolean expression. I don't know the properties at compile time.

Comment: That's not something you can really do... in theory you do some heavy-duty dynamic SQL on your database, but I cannot imagine a situation where that would be a desirable plan of action.  the closest practical equivalent for this is writing some stored procedures/ views for your data.  It won't be dynamic to the level you are desiring, but it's considered a much better practice for a multitude of reasons.

Comment: Sorry but I don't agree with you that it cannot be done unless you can provide an explanation of why. The fact that LINQ to SQL exists at all is proof that it has been done. It's been done in ENtityFramework, and in NHIbernate, and even in the MongoDB C# client (except that compiles to MongoDB queries rather than SQL ones). I want the same thing those do, but with the ability to just generate the SQL code into a string without having those frameworks execute it for me.

Comment: Ummm... no, it hasn't.  In all of your examples (except Mongo, I can't speak to it never having used it before) there is no dynamic boolean pool like you are referring to in the database.  There are lambda expressions in the ORM object models, but that has absolutely nothing to do with the database.  In those cases, someone has written a front-end in code to basically do sorta what my answer is... except with parameterized queries.  The functionality you are talking about is exclusively in the ORM.

Comment: When you use LINQ to query data in something like NHibernate, the lambda expressions you write to define your `WHERE` (along with the `select`, `group by`, etc, but I only care about the `where`) get compiled into SQL. That is what I want. You can compile a string into a lamba or an Expression Tree, and you can compile a lambda into a SQL query. If the string I want to convert is C#, and  I have to compile that straight into a lamda, and then use a conversion process to compile from the lambda to SQL, that will work. I don't think you understand what I'm asking, or I'm not asking it right.

Comment: I'm trying to tell you, the compiling into SQL is a part of the ORM, and intended to be handled internally.  I do not think you can get what you are looking for without involving a mapper like LINQ to SQL, NHibernate, or Entities Framework... unless you write your own.

Comment: "Hard" is not the same as not possible.

Comment: Well, if you want "Hard", you can download the source for NHibernate, and puzzle through how they create SQL.  I don't thing L2SQL or EF will allow you to poke through the source code.

Comment: Jeremy, I want to apologize if I came off as rude. I am just not in a great mood today, and I appreciate you trying to help answer my question.